# Search and delete null values in arrays in collection with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have such object:

```
[{
  title: 'first',
  someField: 'someValue',
  someArr: [1,2,null,null,5,null],
  someNestedObj: {
    title: 'firstNested',
    someField: 'someNestedValue',
    someNestedArr: [null,null,3],
      someNestedNestedObj: {
      title: 'firstNestedNested',
      someField: 'someNestedNestedValue',
      someNestedNestedArr: [1,2,null]
    }
  }
},
{
  title: 'second',
  someField: 'someValue',
  someArr: [1,2,null,null,5,null],
  someNestedObj: {
    title: 'firstNested',
    someField: 'someNestedValue',
    someNestedArr: [null,null,3],
      someNestedNestedObj: {
      title: 'firstNestedNested',
      someField: 'someNestedNestedValue',
      someNestedNestedArr: [1,2,null]
    }
  }
}]
```

What is the fastest method to remove null from arrays within nested properties?

I tried to solve it with `_.omit` & `_.omitBy` but this wasn't a good idea...
maybe someone has a good solution?

Comment: Does it have to be done with lodash?

Comment: @errata preferably - yes

Comment: I guess what @errata is asking is would native javascript be acceptable?

Comment: @Yoda i got it)) but preferably lodash, plain js - could be as well

Comment: What @Yoda said... :)

Comment: You are looking for deep omit. You can recursive loop and omit all `null` or use some other plugin like https://www.npmjs.com/package/omit-deep-lodash

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion to loop data and filter out nulls if value is array.

```js
var data = [{"title":"first","someField":"someValue","someArr":[1,2,null,null,5,null],"someNestedObj":{"title":"firstNested","someField":"someNestedValue","someNestedArr":[null,null,3],"someNestedNestedObj":{"title":"firstNestedNested","someField":"someNestedNestedValue","someNestedNestedArr":[1,2,null]}}},{"title":"second","someField":"someValue","someArr":[1,2,null,null,5,null],"someNestedObj":{"title":"firstNested","someField":"someNestedValue","someNestedArr":[null,null,3],"someNestedNestedObj":{"title":"firstNestedNested","someField":"someNestedNestedValue","someNestedNestedArr":[1,2,null]}}}]

function deleteNull(data) {
  for(var i in data) {
    if(Array.isArray(data[i])) data[i] = data[i].filter(e => e != null)
    if(typeof data[i] == 'object') deleteNull(data[i])
  }
}

deleteNull(data)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way (though, you have to be careful with variable names in here) so applied only with domain knowledge:

```
var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(src).split('null,').join('').split(',null').join('').split('null').join(''))
```

where src is your source object. result is your object w/o nulls.

Basically you remove nulls with string operations, so if 'null' will be a part of a property name or a string value, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lodash#cloneDeepWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeepWith) and [`lodash#reject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reject) to remove all `null` values using [`lodash#isNull`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isNull). Note that `lodash#cloneDeepWith` recursively traverse arrays and objects as long as you don't return the desired result. To continue on traversing the null-filtered arrays, we have to use [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) with `lodash#cloneDeepWith` all over again.

```
var result = _.cloneDeepWith(data, function cb(v) {
  if(_.isArray(v)) {
    return _(v).reject(_.isNull)
      .map(_.partial(_.cloneDeepWith, _, cb)).value();
  }
});
```

```js
var data = [{
  title: 'first',
  someField: 'someValue',
  someArr: [1,2,null,null,5,null],
  someNestedObj: {
    title: 'firstNested',
    someField: 'someNestedValue',
    someNestedArr: [null,null,3],
      someNestedNestedObj: {
      title: 'firstNestedNested',
      someField: 'someNestedNestedValue',
      someNestedNestedArr: [1,2,null]
    }
  }
},
{
  title: 'second',
  someField: 'someValue',
  someArr: [1,2,null,null,5,null],
  someNestedObj: {
    title: 'firstNested',
    someField: 'someNestedValue',
    someNestedArr: [null,null,3],
      someNestedNestedObj: {
      title: 'firstNestedNested',
      someField: 'someNestedNestedValue',
      someNestedNestedArr: [1,2,null]
    }
  }
}];

var result = _.cloneDeepWith(data, function cb(v) {
  if(_.isArray(v)) {
    return _(v).reject(_.isNull)
      .map(_.partial(_.cloneDeepWith, _, cb)).value();
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```